# Correct way to get JavaScript results for HTML use using JSON encoded array & AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Although this is working code i need to just check with the pro's to make sure that this is the correct way to process results so that they can be used in HTML...

(The information that is being requested is from a JSON encoded PHP array of a MYSQL database query)

**JavaScript:**

```
function getPlaylist() {
    var xmlhttp,
    timer;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var list = eval ('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
            {

                document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
                document.getElementById("list0title").innerHTML=list[0].title;
                document.getElementById("list0label").innerHTML=list[0].label;
                document.getElementById("list0albumyear").innerHTML=list[0].albumyear;
                document.getElementById("list0picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '" width="169" height="169"/>';
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.onerror = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "playlist.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    timer = setTimeout(getPlaylist, 1000);
}
```

And then in html, is it correct to use the `body onload="getPlaylist()` command to load the JavaScript function? And is it correct to output my JavaScript variables using `div id="list0artist`?

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/testsite/OneSecondPlaylist.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="getPlaylist()">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="list0artist"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="list0title"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use eval [(eval is evil)](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

To get the result of your xmlHttpRequest, you can use the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method

So, in your code, replace the `list` assignement by:

**Update:** bests practices for a clearer js development

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        // Simple checkup to verify the well functionment of JSON.parse
        // If the xmlhttp.responseText isn't JSON valid, the browser goto the `catch` part (see below)
        try {
            var list = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            if (list && typeof list === 'object') {

                // your list seems to be an array of object ?
                // so, we loop on this list
                // if list contains 0 element, this part is skipped
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                    var currentItem = list[i];

                    document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML = currentItem[0].artist;
                    // to continue ;-)
                }

            }

        } catch(e) {

            throw new Error("Bad response...");

        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. im just reading throught the document you linked... What do you think about the documentgetelement lines of code.. is this the best way to return plain strings of text

Comment: the code is no longer outputting data, i added a "}" to the end of the code because i think one was missing but still no joy... (just incase this helps here is what my encoded data looks like) http://jsfiddle.net/Musicman/PWQN2/

Comment: The console is showing an OK response for the "playlist.php" but it is escaping the loop and i am getting your "bad responce" message

Comment: is it because you have 
"document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=currentItem[0].artist;"

and it should be 
"document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;"